# How to write One data to Two MySQL NDB Cluster?

Tags: mysql-cluster

My company decided to upgrade the current MySQL NDB Cluster and reduce node size for increasing . The buy new Cluster machine with 4 nodes. Current cluster has 6 nodes. For make test on new cluster they suggest reprogram the current client scripts for sending same queries to both two clusters. There hundreds of client script we have to modify for doing this.

Eventually we will move all DB to new 4 node cluster and going to drop using current 6 node cluster.

Actually I'm not looking for replication. I just want to write one processed data into both cluster at once. Clusters are has different node size which is makes replication impossible. Also there are no data available in the new cluster yet, and they don't want to clone data to new cluster until stress testing with new cluster is done.

Once I research about MySQL Proxy but I think replication is necessary according to examples on the internet.

What is the most proper way to write a data to both two cluster?

Comment: Why would different cluster size make replication impossible?

Comment: I'm totally strange about NDB Cluster structure. What I read on internet suggest cluster size must same for replication. Also I'm hesitate because of both cluster in different version.